# Excel VBA, Do warnings have a number

Tags: vba, excel

When I merge cells and more than one cell contains values there is a warning that says, that only the upper left value of the range is kept. I know that I can avoid this warning by using:

```
Application.Display = False
```

But I would also like to execute some code when the warning would have appeared.
I once did that for errors with:

```
On Error Resume Next
If Err.Number = 424 Then
...
```

Is there a way to do the same for warnings?

Comment: I don't believe warnings have a number or any other property you can examine programmatically (I've never seen anyone attempt to "trap" warnings the way we trap errors). Generally, you would need to write logic to check for the condition which raises the warning (e.g., within an `If` block) and handle the code that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking the warnings, you can check directly if a cell is part of a merged cell range:

```
Sub testMerge(cell as Range)
    If cell.MergeCells Then
        Debug.Print cell.Address & " is within Merged Range."
        If cell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Address = cell.Address Then
            Debug.Print cell.Address & " is first cell of Merged Range"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That. And ditto for any other host-specific "warnings" (an application implementation detail), which have absolutely nothing to do with run-time errors (a VBA runtime mechanism).